# How to get the number of objects found in each layer of the active autocad drawing

Tags: vba, autocad

Can any one explain me to get the object entites count of the layer 
using vba code acad

Answer (score 2):

I think You should use SelectionSets

```
Public Sub SelsetByLayer()
    Dim ss As AcadSelectionSet
    Dim FilterType(0) As Integer
    Dim FilterData(0) As Variant
    FilterType(0) = 8 ' DXF code of Layer property
    For I = 0 To ThisDrawing.Layers.Count
        ' ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Item(0).Delete
        Set ss = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("test")  ' You need to ensure if such selection set not exist yet .
        FilterData(0) = ThisDrawing.Layers.Item(I).Name
        ss.Select acSelectionSetAll, , , FilterType, FilterData
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to the original answer, about using **selection sets**.

Here it is slightly modified:

```
Public Sub SelsetByLayer()
    Dim ss As AcadSelectionSet
    Dim FilterType(0) As Integer
    Dim FilterData(0) As Variant
    FilterType(0) = 8 ' DXF code of Layer property
    For I = 0 To ThisDrawing.Layers.Count
        Set ss = CreateSelectionSet("test")
        FilterData(0) = ThisDrawing.Layers.Item(I).Name
        ss.Select acSelectionSetAll, , , FilterType, FilterData
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CreateSelectionSet(SelName As String) As AcadSelectionSet

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Create a new selection set
    ' Delete any existing selection set with the specified name
    With ThisDrawing
        Set CreateSelectionSet = .SelectionSets.Add(SelName)
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            Err.Clear
            .SelectionSets.Item(SelName).Delete
            Set CreateSelectionSet = .SelectionSets.Add(SelName)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

I have added in the missing method for managing the deletion of existing selection set.

`ss.Count` will have the number of entities found. But please bear in mind that you may have layers **frozen** off etc. in the drawing and I think these will be *excluded* from the totals.